# Nim 1.4 Compile - Modify default compile flags on MacOS - issue with clang ld: library not found for -lrt

Tags: nim-lang

For some reason on my Mac when I am using nim 1.4 with `clang` it always builds with the `-lrt` compile flag which breaks since that's not on Macs.

So every time I need to do `nim c --listCmd [my nim file].nim`, get the compile command and delete the `-lrt` before running again, which works fine.

There must be some setting that's making nim or nimble always include `-lrt` in the compile flags but I don't know how to go about troubleshooting this.

I'm stuck on 1.4 due to some `{.requiresInit.}` issues that break in 1.6.

MacOS 12.1 - ARM
Nim 1.4

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue. Can you post your full build command, config.nims, and nim.cfg? AFAICT, nim will not pass -lrt linker flag for the macOS platform from its config files nor std modules (posix). A third party module may be setting `{.passl: "-lrt"}`.

Comment: Note I am on Nim 1.4, but no `nim.cfg`, just a nimble file with requires "nim >= 1.4.0"
requires "rbtree >= 0.5.0"
requires "msgpack4nim"
requires "nimrdkafka"
requires "ulid >= 0.2.1"
requires "redis". Running `nim c -o marketplace src/marketplace` gets to the Linker and I always get these flags at the end of `clang -o ...  -lm -lz -lpthread -lrt   -ldl'

Comment: Looks like [nimrdkafka passes "-lrt"](https://github.com/dfdeshom/nimrdkafka/blob/6d18bed51922fc44f3565566b67e35b37dc5ce70/nimrdkafka.nim#L48).

Comment: The only workaround I can think of is to edit the file in `~/.nimble/pkgs/nimrdkafka-x.x.x` and add a [when clause](https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/blob/a90cabbe40b2367488d94b70e2b5a2c08abce991/lib/posix/posix_haiku.nim#L17) to passL depending on the platform. Also, raising an issue or PR on GitHub if this resolves your issue.

Comment: Thanks! That's a lot of frustration cleared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to hola for finding out that one of my dependencies always passes `-lrt`, https://github.com/dfdeshom/nimrdkafka/blob/6d18bed51922fc44f3565566b67e35b37dc5ce70/nimrdkafka.nim#L48

Solution would have to be to modify that import.